# Getting error in publishing page : unable to persist the fredhopper XML through the webservice

Tags: 2013-sp1, smarttarget, fredhopper, linux

I am trying to setup a SmartTarget 2014 SP1 with Tridion 2013 Sp1 and i have fredhopper installed on Linux environment. I have deployed SmartTarget deployment webservice by .war file and webservice is accessible on content delivery server as well as on content manager server.
But while publishing the page, i am getting error mentioned below:-

> 2015-10-13 22:38:57,240 DEBUG DeployPipelineExecutor - Failure in
>   Phase: Deployment Processing Phase attempt: 1 for transaction:
>   tcm:0-2398454-66560 2015-10-13 22:38:57,240 ERROR
>   DeployPipelineExecutor - Final attempt in Phase: Deployment Processing
>   Phase failed for transaction: tcm:0-2398454-66560 2015-10-13
>   22:38:57,255 ERROR DeployPipelineExecutor - Original stack trace for
>   transaction: tcm:0-2398454-66560
>   com.tridion.deployer.ProcessingException: unable to persist the
>   fredhopper XML through the webservice

Full log is as below:-

> 2015-10-13 22:38:57,240 DEBUG DeployPipelineExecutor - Failure in Phase: Deployment Processing Phase attempt: 1 for transaction: tcm:0-2398454-66560
>   2015-10-13 22:38:57,240 ERROR DeployPipelineExecutor - Final attempt in Phase: Deployment Processing Phase failed for transaction: tcm:0-2398454-66560
>   2015-10-13 22:38:57,255 ERROR DeployPipelineExecutor - Original stack trace for transaction: tcm:0-2398454-66560
>   com.tridion.deployer.ProcessingException: unable to persist the fredhopper XML through the webservice
>       at com.tridion.smarttarget.deployer.fredhopper.WebserviceDeployer.deploy(WebserviceDeployer.java:50) ~[smarttarget_core.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.smarttarget.utils.SmartTargetXMLUtils.persistFredhopperXML(SmartTargetXMLUtils.java:192) ~[smarttarget_core.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.smarttarget.deployer.FredhopperOutputBuilder.persistFredhopperXML(FredhopperOutputBuilder.java:119) ~[smarttarget_core.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.smarttarget.deployer.FredhopperDeployerModule.process(FredhopperDeployerModule.java:76) ~[smarttarget_core.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.Processor.process(Processor.java:109) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.workers.ProcessorWorker.doWork(ProcessorWorker.java:77) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.phases.ProcessingPhase.execute(ProcessingPhase.java:73) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.runMainExecutePhase(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:198) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.doExecute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:100) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.execute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:64) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager.handleDeployPackage(TransactionManager.java:82) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.queue.QueueLocationHandler$1.run(QueueLocationHandler.java:180) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_55]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_55]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_55]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_55]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_55]
>   Caused by: com.tridion.deployer.ProcessingException: webservice received but failed to deploy fredhopper xml. see webservice logs for details.
>       at com.tridion.smarttarget.deployer.fredhopper.WebserviceDeployer.deploy(WebserviceDeployer.java:44) ~[smarttarget_core.jar:na]
>       ... 16 common frames omitted
>   2015-10-13 22:38:57,255 INFO  TransactionPersistence - Removing deployment transaction information: tcm:0-2398454-66560
>   2015-10-13 22:38:57,255 ERROR DeployPipelineExecutor - Unable to start processing deployment package with transactionId: tcm:0-2398454-66560
>   com.tridion.deployer.ProcessingException: Phase: Deployment Processing Phase failed. 
>   unable to persist the fredhopper XML through the webservice
>       at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.runMainExecutePhase(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:209) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.doExecute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:100) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.execute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:64) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager.handleDeployPackage(TransactionManager.java:82) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.queue.QueueLocationHandler$1.run(QueueLocationHandler.java:180) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_55]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_55]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_55]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_55]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_55]
>   Caused by: com.tridion.deployer.ProcessingException: webservice received but failed to deploy fredhopper xml. see webservice logs for details.
>       at com.tridion.smarttarget.deployer.fredhopper.WebserviceDeployer.deploy(WebserviceDeployer.java:44) ~[smarttarget_core.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.smarttarget.utils.SmartTargetXMLUtils.persistFredhopperXML(SmartTargetXMLUtils.java:192) ~[smarttarget_core.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.smarttarget.deployer.FredhopperOutputBuilder.persistFredhopperXML(FredhopperOutputBuilder.java:119) ~[smarttarget_core.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.smarttarget.deployer.FredhopperDeployerModule.process(FredhopperDeployerModule.java:76) ~[smarttarget_core.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.Processor.process(Processor.java:109) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.workers.ProcessorWorker.doWork(ProcessorWorker.java:77) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.phases.ProcessingPhase.execute(ProcessingPhase.java:73) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.runMainExecutePhase(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:198) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       ... 9 common frames omitted

Fredhopper deployment agent and indexer are running and accessible. 
Fredhopper Business manager is also running.

I am not getting where and what i have missed. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

I have checked the logs but there is no much information in Kitchen.log file. But i got the below WARN message in fredhopper.log. [root@ip-10-120-11-163 /]# cd /apps/fredhopper/data/instances/dev/log [root@ip-10-120-11-163 log]# cat fredhopper.log 2015-10-13 02:53:05,397 WARN [http-nio-8180-exec-3] FredhopperBasePage.java:103 Page 'campaigns.fh' will not be rendered for user 'Unknown' since he / she has neither WRITE nor READ privileges for it. [root@ip-10-120-11-163 log]# Could you please advise on this.

SmartTarget Deployment Webservice is also running separately.

I am following the SDL doc Link On point #7 is optional but at the same time i have the default setting is set for authentication in smartTarget_config.xml in the  element  admin encrypted:56StnjmsTNnHdITMkL4KYw==

My SmartTarget Deployment Webservice is hosted on linux environment with Fredhopper. I am getting the below error of wrong path where i have changed my path to smarttarget_conf.xml 2015-10-14 08:50:38,313 DEBUG SmartTargetDeployment - retreiving xml document for transaction tcm_0-2398473-66560 2015-10-14 08:50:38,318 ERROR SmartTargetDeployment - error persisting fredhopper xml javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/fredhopper/indexer/data/fas-xml-incremental/catalog01/tcm_0-2398473-66560_‌​component Don't know from where this path configured.

I have checked the path in SmartTargetDeploymentWebService_conf.xml and it is as per my requirement. But still service is picking the path mentioned in logs.
Just to verify that log will change, i deleted the SmartTargetDeploymentWebService_conf.xml file but still i am getting the same error.

No clues from where service is picking the path.
Is there any default path which service consuming?

Thanks

New:-After restarting Tomcat and publishing again, i found the below information in service logs:-

> 2015-10-14 10:58:32,763 DEBUG SmartTargetDeployment - loaded
>   fredhopper location
>   /apps/fredhopper/dev/data/fas-xml-incremental/catalog01

But there is nothing in catalog folder and publishing also got failed.

Comment: Is the separate web service also running? If that's the case, the best place to check is in the Fredhopper logs, at `data/instances/deployments/log/kitchen.log` and `data/instances/<INDEX>/log/fredhopper.log`

Comment: @Raimond I have checked the logs but there is no much information in Kitchen.log file. But i got the below WARN message in fredhopper.log.

`[root@ip-10-120-11-163 /]# cd /apps/fredhopper/data/instances/dev/log
[root@ip-10-120-11-163 log]# cat fredhopper.log
2015-10-13 02:53:05,397 WARN  [http-nio-8180-exec-3] FredhopperBasePage.java:103 Page 'campaigns.fh' will not be rendered for user 'Unknown' since he / she has neither WRITE nor READ privileges for it.
[root@ip-10-120-11-163 log]#`

Could you please advise on this.

Comment: Yes SmartTarget Deployment Webservice is also running separately.

Comment: Hmm... Have configured the account settings properly in `smarttarget_conf.xml` ?

Comment: @Raimond i am following the SDL doc [Link](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2014_SP1-v1/GUID-8D2EE604-2C43-4793-A333-B5146F00BB72) 
On  point #7 is optional but at the same time i have the default setting is set for authentication in `smartTarget_config.xml` in the `<IndexServer>` element

`<Authentication>
                <Username>admin</Username>
                <Password>encrypted:56StnjmsTNnHdITMkL4KYw==</Password>
            </Authentication>`

Comment: It is easier to read for everybody if you edit the question and provide this additional info in there, no need to reply to a comment by a comment.

Comment: @Sumit, Can you check the smart target deployment webservice log for more information? If you have deployed it on tomcat, you should be able to see the log file location in logback.xml which should be in location like this C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\SmartTargetDeploymentWebService\WEB-INF\classes\logback.xml

Comment: Also check your web server where smart target deployment webservice hosted? If the web server is j2ee compliant the war should be installed from /j2ee folder, if not j2ee-complaint server should be installed from nonJ2ee folder

Comment: @ARRX My SmartTarget Deployment Webservice is hosted on linux environment with Fredhopper. I am getting the below error of wrong path where i have changed my path to smarttarget_conf.xml
`2015-10-14 08:50:38,313 DEBUG SmartTargetDeployment - retreiving xml document for transaction tcm_0-2398473-66560
2015-10-14 08:50:38,318 ERROR SmartTargetDeployment - error persisting fredhopper xml
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/fredhopper/indexer/data/fas-xml-incremental/catalog01/tcm_0-2398473-66560_component`

Don't know from where this path configured.

Comment: @Sumit, thats a good finding! the location of that path would be in config file SmartTargetDeploymentWebService_conf.xml (this config file should be in same path as logback.xml C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\SmartTargetDeploymentWebService\WEB-INF\classes\)

Comment: @Sumit, as Bart suggested, edit your original question and put your findings/additional info there, for readability!

Comment: @Sumit, it should be coming from the config file, its worth restarting your web server and restart your application and check in the logs whether it picks up correct path?

Comment: After restarting Tomcat, logs are not getting generated. Publishing stuck at the same point. Don't know what to do now.

Comment: Can you check if you have configured the Smart Target deployment webservice correctly? Specifically the fredhopper catalog location..

Comment: @Sumit, Do you have any update on this issue? If it is resolved, please provide the resolution, it might help others.